# How to condense a dataset with dates in R

Tags: r, database, spreadsheet

I'm trying to take some data and clean it for end user visibility, however I'm new to R and can't quite seem to figure out how to go about it. Also, this is my first post, so please let me know if there are any formatting or structural issues to the way I wrote this question.

What the data looks like right now:

| name | date | reason |
| --- | --- | --- |
| john | 1/1/2022 | late |
| john | 1/2/2022 | late |
| john | 1/4/2022 | absent |
| betty | 1/3/2022 | absent |
| betty | 1/5/2022 | no call |
| betty | 1/7/2022 | no call |
| kyle | 1/3/2022 | absent |
| kyle | 1/5/2022 | no call |
| kyle | 1/7/2022 | no call |

I want to see if there's a way to condense this so that for every name, you have the date and reason all on the same line. Like this:

| name | date1 | reason1 | date2 | reason2 | date3 | reason3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| john | 1/1/2022 | late | 1/2/2022 | late | 1/4/2022 | absent |
| betty | 1/3/2022 | absent | 1/5/2022 | no call | 1/7/2022 | no call |
| kyle | 1/3/2022 | absent | 1/5/2022 | no call | 1/7/2022 | no call |

Alternatively, I tried using `dcast`, but my code produced numbers instead of dates.

```
new db <- dcast(db, name ~ reason, fun.aggregate = list, value.var = "date")
```

What I wanted:

| name | late | absent | no call |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| john | 1/1/2022,1/2/2022 | 1/4/2022 |  |
| betty |  | 1/3/2022 | 1/5/2022,1/7/2022 |
| kyle |  | 1/3/2022 | 1/5/2022,1/7/2022 |

What I got:

| name | late | absent | no call |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| john | c(1620708300,1627236300) | 1639328820 | numeric(0) |
| betty | numeric(0) | 1612973940 | c(1611937080, 1612455480) |
| kyle | numeric(0) | 1639329540 | c(1635526800, 1639760400) |

**EDIT:**

I was able to get it inches away from where I need it to be using `as.data.frame(pivot_wider(df, names_from=reason, values_from=date,  values_fn=list, values_fill=list("")))` thanks to [@Andre Wildberg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9462095/andre-wildberg), the last step that I need is to remove the c() from the cells and be able to display clean dates in those fields.

```
db<-structure(list(name = c("Debby", "Debby", "Debby", 
"Debby", "Robert", "Robert", "Robert", 
"Ryan", "Ryan", "Ryan", "Ryan", 
"Ryan", "Ryan", "Brandon", "Brandon"
), reason = c("Absent", "Leave Early", "Late", "Leave Early", 
"Leave Early", "Leave Early", "Absent", "Absent", "Absent", "Absent", 
"Absent", "Leave Early", "Late", "Leave Early", "Leave Early"
), date = c("2021-05-11 04:45:00", "2021-05-15 04:02:00", "2021-07-25                     
18:05:00", 
"2021-09-19 20:01:00", "2021-11-25 01:02:00", "2021-12-08 20:56:00", 
"2021-12-16 17:30:00", "2021-10-09 17:00:00", "2021-11-07 17:00:00", 
"2021-11-12 17:00:00", "2021-11-28 17:00:00", "2021-12-11 01:31:00", 
"2021-12-12 17:07:00", "2021-05-03 23:58:00", "2021-05-15 23:31:00"
)), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reshape data from long to wide format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/how-to-reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this if you want to keep the observations combined

```
library(tidyr)

as.data.frame(pivot_wider(df, names_from=reason, values_from=date, 
  values_fn=list, values_fill=list("")))
     name
1   Debby
2  Robert
3    Ryan
4 Brandon
                                                                              Absent
1                                                                2021-05-11 04:45:00
2                                                                2021-12-16 17:30:00
3 2021-10-09 17:00:00, 2021-11-07 17:00:00, 2021-11-12 17:00:00, 2021-11-28 17:00:00
4                                                                                   
                               Leave Early                Late
1 2021-05-15 04:02:00, 2021-09-19 20:01:00 2021-07-25 18:05:00
2 2021-11-25 01:02:00, 2021-12-08 20:56:00                    
3                      2021-12-11 01:31:00 2021-12-12 17:07:00
4 2021-05-03 23:58:00, 2021-05-15 23:31:00
```

##### Data

```
df <- structure(list(name = c("Debby", "Debby", "Debby", "Debby", "Robert", 
"Robert", "Robert", "Ryan", "Ryan", "Ryan", "Ryan", "Ryan", "Ryan", 
"Brandon", "Brandon"), reason = c("Absent", "Leave Early", "Late", 
"Leave Early", "Leave Early", "Leave Early", "Absent", "Absent", 
"Absent", "Absent", "Absent", "Leave Early", "Late", "Leave Early", 
"Leave Early"), date = c("2021-05-11 04:45:00", "2021-05-15 04:02:00", 
"2021-07-25 18:05:00", "2021-09-19 20:01:00", "2021-11-25 01:02:00", 
"2021-12-08 20:56:00", "2021-12-16 17:30:00", "2021-10-09 17:00:00", 
"2021-11-07 17:00:00", "2021-11-12 17:00:00", "2021-11-28 17:00:00", 
"2021-12-11 01:31:00", "2021-12-12 17:07:00", "2021-05-03 23:58:00", 
"2021-05-15 23:31:00")), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: This is making my dates read as "c(1637802120, 1638996960)" , is there a way to format these as dates at this point?

Comment: @QuinnLangton You can prevent this by storing the date as character.

Comment: @QuinnLangton You can alternatively do `dput(head(data,10))` and update the question. I can then take a closer look!

Comment: Updated! Though, I used the actual sheet I'm using, not the examples. So many more dates on the actual sheet.

Comment: @QuinnLangton Hm, something must have gone wrong while using `dput`. It should have `structure(` at the beginning like in my example in the Data section.

Comment: I think that was just a me being new and not knowing what I'm doing thing. Should be fixed now.

Comment: @QuinnLangton You sure this is the right dataset? Has no column `reason`. Looks like its already in wide format.

Comment: So sorry! I sent my `dput` after I already ran your code, this is what I have before.

Comment: @QuinnLangton I ran the same line on the updated `df` and it seems to be ok. See edit. I manually corrected the newline `\n` though. The dates are already in character form, so that should also be ok!